# Magento 2: Update specific input field class via Knockout

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, input, knockout

I would like to update / add a class to a **specific** **text** **input** field via Knockout (as opposed to just using JQuery).

For example, I'd like to add another class to the input below.

And, more importantly, if I were to also want to update the 'value' and 'id' via the bindings, how would one do that?

[image]

Comment: You can override this file in your theme and check condition for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

#### Overwrite the template

You can overwrite the template and add the class, to do this copy the template file into your theme and add your class.

Based off your question I suspect the template is [this one](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/input.html)

The downside of this is it will affect every text input on the website, if this is what you intend then this method will work.

#### Create a new template

If you only want your new class to appear in certain areas of the website then you'll need to create a new template and use that one.

This can be done with the following layout XML.

```
<item name="field-you-want-to-change" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Package_Theme/form/element/input-custom.html</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If I were to also want to update the 'value' and 'id' via the bindings, how would one do that?

Comment: I think you would need to modify or extend the related JS, which in this instance I think is `Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/text.js` or possibly even `Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/abstract.js`. I haven't done a lot with so I'd need some time to provide an in depth answer sorry.